# SpringBoot application - AuditorAware transaction is not committed with Postgres DB

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to load spring boot application with pre-existing data. I want to populate data with the "system" user. I have following component definition which gets intercepted and creates a "system" user. The problem is this component **transaction gets committed to the database when running the spring boot application against H2** but it is **it doesn't get committed when application is run with PostgreSQL datasource**. Please help me to figure out how to get the transaction commmitted?

The overridden implementation of getCurrentAuditor method is as below

```
@Transactional
@Component("auditorProvider")
public class UserAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User> {

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private User _systemUser;

    @Override
    public User getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            if (_systemUser != null) {
                return _systemUser;
            }
            Optional<User> systemUser = userRepository.findOneByUsername("system");
            if (!systemUser.isPresent()) {
                // TODO: decide on which user to designate when entities are created by devices
                User user = new User("system");
                user = userRepository.save(user);
                userRepository.flush();
                systemUser = Optional.of(user);
            }
            _systemUser = systemUser.get();
            return _systemUser;
        }
        CurrentUser userDetails = (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return userDetails.getUser();
    }
}
```

The main application class has following annotations.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to REQUIRES_NEW propagation value to resolve this problem. It creates the new transaction and suspends if there is existing one. Not sure why the default propagation is not working.

```
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Component("auditorProvider")
public class UserAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User> {

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private User _systemUser;

    @Override
    public User getCurrentAuditor() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            if (_systemUser != null) {
                return _systemUser;
            }
            Optional<User> systemUser = userRepository.findOneByUsername("system");
            if (!systemUser.isPresent()) {
                // TODO: decide on which user to designate when entities are created by devices
                User user = new User("system");
                user = userRepository.save(user);
                userRepository.flush();
                systemUser = Optional.of(user);
            }
            _systemUser = systemUser.get();
            return _systemUser;
        }
        CurrentUser userDetails = (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return userDetails.getUser();
    }
}
```